# How to use dpkg-divert to temporarily remove/replace symlink when package is installed?

Tags: debian, package-management, dpkg, packaging

The default nginx package creates a symlink named `default` in the `sites-enabled` dir, which points to a default config file in `sites-available`. I'm currently creating a package for an app that sits on top of Nginx, and I want to remove or move away the `default` symlink, and replace it with the config file from my package. Ideally, in the event that my package is removed, the original `default` symlink will be restored.

I've been reading the manpage and examples of `dpkg-divert`, but I don't quite see that it can do this. Is this achievable with `dpkg-divert`, or do I have to think of another way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to divert a file owned by another package:

- In your preinst, divert the file away.

  ```
  dpkg-divert --add --package $your_package_name --rename \
     --divert /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.disabled \
              /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
  ```
- In your postrm, divert the file back.

  ```
  dpkg-divert --remove --package $your_package_name --rename \
              /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
  ```

This won't work for the symlink `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`, because it's created by the `nginx` package's postinst rather than being part of the package. Since the symlink is part of the package, you can just rename it with `mv`. I don't know if this is compliant with the Debian packaging policy; if this matters to you, as this is a rather specialized question, I recommend searching or asking on [debian-devel](http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/).